# Compare two spreadsheets using python or perl

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, xlrd, xlutils

I like to compare two spreadsheets. Lets say file1.xls and file2.xls. I like to go compare file1 records with file2 column records. If there is a match with any particular cell I like to update a specific column on file2.xls (for example say there is a column in file2.xls called match.)

Example:

We need to compare file1.xls with File2.xls based on hostname and if there is a match, we will append yes under match column

File1.xls (there can be blank cells)

```
Hostname | IP Address 

server1  | 192.168.1.1

server2  | 192.168.2.1
```

File2.xls

```
Location | Hostname | IP Address  | Match 

Rack1    | server1  | 192.168.1.1 | Yes    (the script will enter yes under match here)

Rack2    | server3  | 192.168.2.2 |         (there will be no match here)      

Rack3    | server2  | 192.168.2.1 | yes
```

Can someone help me here ? Could be python or perl as I need to run this on different platforms not just windows.

Comment: What have *you* tried? Off the top of my head, I'll open both and store the columns in two lists, and straight up compare them, creating another list of `Yes`es and `No`s. Then put that list back in the second file. Seems plausible, yes?